# include('file.php') vs include 'file.php'?

Tags: php

Are these the same?

```
include('file.php');
// vs
include 'file.php';
```

I know these both work just the same, but just wanted to know when or why are you using one or the other.

Thanks!

Comment: They're exactly the same. End of question. Please remove this, as there isn't a real problem here.

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): `Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.`

Comment: @AaronGilion they are not exactly the same

Comment: @self - then explain in what way they are different, don't simply make a statement like that without justifying why tyou believe that the PHP docs are wrong

Comment: @self, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @AaronGillion, I think you're over reacting a little bit. Why so nervous, mate? I've looked it up in the documentation and there is a little bit of difference. The only problem is that I don't quite understand it. Check it yourself: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.include.php `<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == TRUE), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == TRUE) {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == TRUE) {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>`

Comment: @MattE. well, you didn't say you were using an `if` statement! That changes the question!

Comment: `include(('vars.php') == TRUE)`.... compare a string containing `vars.php` with a boolean, giving a boolean true/false..... and then `include` that boolean result..... not exactly sensible coding, how many filenames have you ever come across that are PHP boolean values? Filenames are strings in most filesystems that I've encountered

Comment: `if (include('vars.php') == TRUE)` is perfectly valid coding.... an include can return a value, and that value can be tested in a comparison, so this isn't invalid

Comment: // doesnt work: `if (include('vars.php') == TRUE)`
// works: `if ((include 'vars.php') == TRUE)`

Comment: they are not the same thing because the expressions are different on the right side of `include` I'm not sure if you know you're BNF grammar, but take a look at `zend_language_parser.y` those two statements are NOT the same. End of story. They probably give you the same result, but they aren't the same.